# Regarding Custom HTML Form for Itinerary section in Django Admin Panel

Tags: django-forms

I want to create the "Itinerary section" form like attachment image.
If any have idea about custom HTML template as per provided by designer and also need to create the form:

[image]

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, and it's not even a question. You might want to re-write it.

Comment: I want to create the Custom HTML Form in admin panel. So any one can let me know about this.